# Jetty: how do I get unbuffered InputStream or Reader from request (to "stream" events over HTTP)?

Tags: java, http, servlets, stream, jetty

I am experimenting with sending events over an established HTTP "connection".

It works when done to "stream events" from server in server's `HttpServletResponse`: by setting the buffer size of client to a very small value, and doing `HttpServletResponse.flushBuffer()` periodically on the server side.

```
works:
1) [client] --> (usual GET request) --> [server]
2) [client] <-- event...pause...event...pause...event <-- [server]
```

However, the other direction doesn't work: I can't affect the buffer size for HttpServletRequest (to be able to "stream events" during client's request).

```
doesn't work:
1) [client] --> event...pause...event...pause...event --> [server]
```

**Are there ways to interact with requests/responses beneath the servlet abstraction, to be able to achieve my goal?**

*(When using usual servlets, I deal with already constructed requests, where buffer size is pre-set.)*

**Any other thoughts?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something similar [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).
**WebSocket** is a web technology providing for bi-directional, full-duplex communications channels, over a single Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) socket.